# redirect after 5 seconds using multithreading in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view without button and i want to redirect after 5 seconds to index view. I want to use multi threading timer or jquery.

I try search in google but i didn't found what that i want.

I try use:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/jquery-redirect-to-another-page-after-5.html?m=1

this link but didn't work

How to make it?

thanks

Comment: Clicking the link worked for me (unless you meant what the content of the link describes did not work for you then you need to include details in your question about what you tried and how it failed or your question is likely to be closed)

Comment: Please add code to your post and what you have tried.  This post may (inevitably) be flagged for low quality if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the javascript function setTimeout()

The idea is that once you display the view, you call setTimeout() to do a redirect in 5 seconds.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout ( function(){
                             window.location.href = "http://YourServer/Controller/Action";},
                             5000 );                    
    </script>
```